# Using zoo package

Tags: r, zoo

Please help!
I have a .csv file with 4 columns: Date, VBLTX, FMAGX and SBUX. The three latter columns are adjusted closing prices of some stocks. And the date column are the months from Jan-1998 to Dec-2009. Here is the first couple or rows:

```
Date      |VBLTX      |FMAGX        |SBUX  
1/01/1998 |4.36       |44.38        |4.3  
1/02/1998 |4.34       |47.74        |4.66  
1/03/1998 |4.35       |47.74        |5.33
```

I am trying to read this into R as a zoo object that should look like this:

```
         |VBLTX      |FMAGX        |SBUX  
Jan 1998 |4.36       |44.38        |4.3  
Feb 1998 |4.34       |47.74        |4.66  
Mar 1998 |4.35       |47.74        |5.33
```

I have no idea how to make this work. I am currently using this line of code:

```
all_prices <- read.zoo("all_prices.csv", FUN = identity)
```

And this produces this zoo series:

```
         |V2         |V3           |V4  
Apr-00   |4.63       |73.15        |7.12  
Apr-01   |5.22       |63.05        |9.11  
Apr-02   |5.71       |53.88        |10.74
```

It appears to have sorted the csv file alphabetically rather than by date. Also if I scroll through the zoo series there is a row which is the column names from the csv file.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have "no idea" how to use a command then read the help file for it carefully -- in this case `?read.zoo`.  Also there is a vignette that comes with zoo entirely devoted to `read.zoo` examples: `vignette("zoo-read")` .  Also reviewing `?yearmon` would be useful here.

Assuming that the input file is as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and NOT as shown in the question it should NOT have a `.csv` extension since it is not a csv file; however, ignoring that we have the following.

`header = TRUE` says the first line is a header, `FUN = as.yearmon` says we want to convert the first column to a `yearmon` class time index and `format` specifies its format (using the percent codes defined in `?strptime`).

```
library(zoo)

read.zoo("all_prices.csv", header = TRUE, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

giving:

```
         VBLTX FMAGX SBUX
Jan 1998  4.36 44.38 4.30
Feb 1998  4.34 47.74 4.66
Mar 1998  4.35 47.74 5.33
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Date      VBLTX      FMAGX        SBUX  
1/01/1998 4.36       44.38        4.3  
1/02/1998 4.34       47.74        4.66  
1/03/1998 4.35       47.74        5.33
"
cat(Lines, file = "all_prices.csv")
```